# Add element if LI has children

Tags: jquery

looking for a way in jQuery to add a little down arrow to each navigation item that has children li's.

So markup of nav is:

```
<div class="mainNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Nav One</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Sub nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sub nav 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Nav Two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So - after the Nav One I am looking to inject a line of code - i class='arrow down' as per code below

I was hoping this would work in jQuery - but it does not... what am I doing wrong? I cant see to target the  to insertAfter it?

```
$('.mainNav ul li').has('ul').children("a").insertAfter("<i class='arrow down'></i>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result with [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) (in case you want the `<i>` tag inside of the `<a>` element):

```js
$('.mainNav ul li').has('ul').children("a").append("<i class='arrow down'></i>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Nav One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub nav 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Nav Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In case you want the `<i>` tag after the `<a>` tag:

```js
$("<i class='arrow down'></i>").insertAfter($('.mainNav ul li').has('ul').children("a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Nav One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub nav 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Nav Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```